# Sorting and comparing lists with a nested for loop

Tags: python, list, sorting, range, nested-for-loop

Im Trying to sort and compare lists with a for loop, but I keep getting the error:

***sorted(lista[str(y+1)]) 

KeyError: '14454'***

Here's my code:

```
l = 0
k = 0
u = 0
lista = {}


sys.stdout = open("1.txt", "w")
for i in range(1,28):
    for j in range(1,28):
        for k in range(1,28):
          a = float(i)
          b = float(j)
          c = float(k)
          q = (a*b*c) / ((a+b+c)*(a+b+c)*(a+b+c))
          if q > (1 / 81) and q < 1:
            if a != b and b != c and c != a:
              lista[str(l)] = [a,b,c]
              l = l + 1

for x in range(l):
    for y in range(l):
        sorted(lista[str(x)])
        sorted(lista[str(y+1)])

        if lista[str(x)] == [str(y+1)]:
            u = u + 1
    
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: `y+1` when `y` goes across `range(l)` is wrong because it goes one past the last element. You, therefore, get the KeyError. There are quite a few other problems I see your code as is, but most of them are irrelevant to your main question. What are you trying to do, overall?

Comment: I think debugging the second nested loop by printing the value of y at each iteration might help in finding the exact value of y that causes the KeyError

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I fixed the KeyError by making "for y in range(L-1)", now, Im trying to figure out why I cant print the variable "u". @UltraInstinct

Answer (score 0):

### The Error (Explained)

```py
KeyError: "14454"
```

means that that the key is non-existent.
For example, if my dict is `{"hi": "hi", "hello": "hello"}`, and I try calling `myDict["hiya"]`, it will return `KeyError: "hiya"`.

#### What should you do?

Well, debug it. By placing `print(lista)` **before the loop** (to avoid the console being overflowed), you can see the keys of `lista` and find your code solution from there!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I fixed the KeyError by making "for y in range(L-1)", now, Im trying to figure out why I cant print the variable "u"